# Toggle button in dynamic/recursive structure

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm looping an array of `element` and I'd want to recursively display that `element` with given `template`

and then inside that template use button with toggle to show/hide deeper level template of `Child`s of given `element` (`Child` is also an `Element`)

```
<div v-for="(element in elements)">
    <MyTemplate :element="element"></MyTemplate>
</div>
```

Here's my template:

```
<template>
    <div>element.Name</div>
    <button @click="toggleSomehow">
        // I'd want to display it under that button when he's "showing"
        <MyTemplate :element="element.Child"></MyTemplate>
    </button>
</template>
```

But I'm not really sure how to do that `SHOW`/`HIDE` button without binding it with some property or array, but I'd rather want to avoid it because everything has to be kind of dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add toggleable data to your `MyComponent` component like `visible`
See example below

```js
Vue.component('my-template', {
  template: '#my-template',
  props: {
    element: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  
  data() {
    return {
      visible: false
    }
  },

  methods: {
    toggleVisible() {
      this.visible = !this.visible
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="my-template">
  <div>
    <div>{{element.name}}</div>
    <button @click="toggleVisible" v-if="element.child">toggle</button>
    <my-template v-if="visible" :element="element.child" />
  </div>
</script>

<div id="app">
  <my-template :element="{name: 'test', child: {name: 'child test'}}" />
</div>
```